# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS wifi hardware disabled

Tags: iwlwifi

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my HP Envy spectre xt 13-2000eg and i just can't get my wifi working.
I have an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 
I also have the gnome shell installed (I don't think thats the problem) when I try to connect to a wifi network it says hardware disabled.
When I run

```
rfkill list
```

I get

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

Further I already checked, but I don't have a hardware switch for wireless connections. Simply trying

```
rfkill unblock all
```

won't do the trick either.

Funny thing is that for a short time the wifi worked but after the reboot i had the same problem again.
Maybe it is intel's iwlwifi? I couldn't figure out how to install that :/

I really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Hard Block cannot be unblocked using the software.

Your WiFi is perhaps turned of by your keyboard WiFi shortcut. It is also possible that it is disabled by your BIOS settings.  Try to enable it using your keyboard shortcut or any other key available in you system. Also check you BIOS settings for any WiFi related settings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The keyboard shortcuts that I know did not work. I've also already looked in the BIOS where I couldn't find any indication that the wifi would be disabled. however for some magic reason (I have absolutely no idea why) it started working again. If it fails again I might have to get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with HP Pavilion G6 and I tried everything including several re-installations. The solution is unbelievably simple. All I did was to load BIOS default setting and the hard block was removed. Working perfectly since then. Try and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update: As I already mentioned in the comment of the answer my wifi now kind of works. 
I figured out that after the restart the wifi is "hardware disabled" however if I suspend (in my case just close the laptop) and then immediately reopen i.e. wake it up again it works.
I have no clue why, but it does.
Maybe this helps someone, too.

Comment: If suspending and resuming enables the device I'm suspecting a BIOS/firmware issue there. Check for updates with your vendor I'd say or try to tweak some BIOS settings if available.

Comment: If it is "hardware disabled", it would not have been worked.